# How to send array from one component to another in vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an vue application where I am saving an array from a datepicker dialog. My datepicker dialog and the inputs are a seperate component from my dialog. Now I want to try sending my array which is saved in the datepicker component to my component where my dialog is and display it by pushing it to another array inside the dialog component. But the array is not being sent.

Datepickercomponent:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "DatePickerComponent",
  data: () => ({
    selectedTime: [],

    dates: [{date : new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10), time: []}],
    menu: false,
    modal: false,
    menu2: false,
  }),

  methods:{
      addTimeFields(){

        this.selectedTime.push({
          startTime:"",
          endTime: "",
        })
        this.dates[0].time.push(
        this.selectedTime
          )
      },

      saveDateAndTIme(){
        console.log(this.selectedTime)
      }
  }



};
</script>
```

Dialog component where I am using a method to get access to the array inside datepicker:

```
data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    date: [],
    menu: false,
    modal: false,
    menu2: false
  }),

     methods:{
         save() {
  this.date.push(
    this.$refs.datepicker.dates
  )
          console.log(this.date)
    
        }
    
    
      }
```

But what this does is just to send the initial array to the date array inside dialog component.
The initial value is `dates: date current date, time []`
I am new to vue maybe it is a small mistake I can not seem to find could someone give me an pointer

Comment: I fixed it I am using this$refs method to access it from my parentcomponent I will add my solution to the updated question

Comment: answer your own question and later mark it as accepted, so another user with the same question can see how to "fix" it 

Comment: I will do it, should I just edit it or post a new answer which is the correct way ?

Comment: just write as a new answer.... and welcome to StackOverflow 

Comment: alright I will do it :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change the save method in the parent component to use the this.$refs in it.

And to change the use of the child component to this:

```
<datepickercomponent ref= "datepicker"/>
```

and

```
data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    date: [],
    menu: false,
    modal: false,
    menu2: false
}),
methods:{
    save() {
    this.date.push(
        this.$refs.datepicker.dates
    )        
}
```